# How to retrieve Site Url and Site Name in Plugin

Tags: plugin-development, globals

I'm having an exceedingly difficult time trying to retrieve the Site URL and Name in a custom plugin I am developing.

My research has led me to believe this would work:

```
$envVar = craft()->config->get('environmentVariables');
$siteUrl = $envVar['siteUrl'];
$siteName = $envVar['siteName'];
```

But in practice this hasn't worked. Does anyone know the correct way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get them via [craft()->getSiteUrl()](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/etc/behaviors/AppBehavior#getSiteUrl-detail) and [craft()->getSiteName()](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/etc/behaviors/AppBehavior#getSiteName-detail).

Answer (score 14):

In Craft 3 you can do this:

```
use craft\helpers\UrlHelper;
UrlHelper::siteUrl();

Craft::$app->sites->currentSite->name;
```

Comment: What about siteName?

Comment: @good_afternoon I just updated my answer to include that.

Answer (score 1):

What you've done should work fine for actual [environment variables](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/multi-environment-configs#environment-specific-variables), but both [siteUrl](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#siteUrl) and [siteName](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#siteName) are proper [config settings](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings) that you can access via `craft()->config->get('siteUrl')` and `craft()->config->get('siteName')`.

Comment: I am still have issues retrieving the values in this way. Note: I am accessing them via an Event, specifically when an entry is saved. Would that have an impact on this?

Comment: Shouldn't. Can you add your `craft/config/general.php` contents to the original question?